# Enabling checkboxes in javascript and getting their values if they are disabled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have following table

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
    foreach($redeemSales as $sale)
    { 
    ?>
    <tr  value='<?php echo $sale['id']; ?>'>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="salesIds[]" value="<?php echo $sale['id']; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $sale["ring"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo formatFullDate($sale["soldDate"]) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sale["saleType"]; ?></td>
        <td>   
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <select name="claimTypes[]" class="form-control redeemOptions">
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="CD">CherieDori Credit (CD)</option>
                    <option value="Amex">American Express Card (Amex)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

On Changing any value of redeemOptions, it should check the corresponding Checkbox. Now i do not want people to automatically click on checkboxes. So i have them disabled , the get checked when i change options in redeemOptions. Here is the javascript code

```
$('.redeemOptions').change(function()
{
    var menuChanged = $(this);

    parentForm = menuChanged.closest('form');
    correspondingCheckbox = parentForm.find('input[name=salesIds]');
    var status = (menuChanged.val() === 'None') ? false : true;
    $(this).closest('tr').children()[0].childNodes[0].checked = status;  
});
```

I have a button, that gets all the saleIds associated with only checked checkboxes

Here is the code

```
$('.redeemBtn').on('click', function()
{
    $('input[name="salesIds[]"]').disabled = false;
    var checked = $('input[name="salesIds[]"]:checked').serialize();
    var cclaim = $('select[name="claimTypes[]"]').serialize();

    if(checked !== '')
        window.location.href = 'actions.php?j=4&' + checked + '&' + cclaim;
    else
        alert('No sales were selected');
});
```

It works fine if i remove the disabled from checkbox otherwise it gives "No sales selected" however i do not want to remove the disabled. I don't want users to interact with it. How can i get values of the checkBoxes that are displaying as being checked. What should be done

Comment: $('input[type="checkbox"]').val() should give you the value regardless if it's disabled or not.

Comment: in my case no, it gives error for val. How can I enable all disabled checkboxes? let's say on button click. $('input[name="salesIds[]"]').disabled = false; doesn't work

Comment: with jQuery need to use `prop()` method ... see docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, you'll need to enable it to see/get it server-side (otherwise the "client won't send it at all"). The browser "doesn't include disabled controls" in the " submission", since they "don't count as "successful" controls".

so better assign some value to this check box by default at the time of your submission.

see this article:http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

**e.g.:**`enable/disable` checkbox on button click

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function chk_control(str) {
if(str=='dsb'){document.getElementById('ck1').disabled=true;}
else {document.getElementById('ck1').disabled=false;}
}
</script>
</head>

<body >

<form name=form1 method=post action=check.php>
<table>

<tr  ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb id=ck1 value=1></td><td >PHP</td></tr>
<tr  ><td ><input type=button value='Disable' onClick="chk_control('dsb')";></td>
<td ><input type=button value='Enable' onClick="chk_control('enb')";></td></tr>
</table></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: easiest way is to enable them, how can i do that at button press

Comment: in the example i'll give a small piece of code just try that out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty common case for webdev. You should add some `hidden` input in this case.

```
<input type="hidden" name="salesIds[]" value="smth">
```

and keep your checkboxes without `name` for "presentation" purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#id of checkbox').prop("disabled", false);
```

This will enable the field. If you need to get the disabled field value just enable it after clicking the submit.This is the easiest way go get values.

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer, showing what it does and how it solves the problem - this will help others in the future who see your answer